# Item Recommendation mahout Java error

Tags: macos, mahout

I'm trying to make an item based recommendation but i got this error:

```
Lore:~ lorenzoferri$ mahout parallelALS --input prova1.csv --output output.csv --lambda 0.1 --implicitFeedback true --alpha 0.8 --numFeatures 2 --numIterations 5  --numThreadsPerSolver 1 --tempDir tmp
No MAHOUT_CONF_DIR found
Running on hadoop, using /usr/local/bin/hadoop and HADOOP_CONF_DIR=
MAHOUT-JOB: /usr/local/Cellar/mahout/0.9/libexec/mahout-examples-0.9-job.jar
15/02/09 17:32:25 WARN driver.MahoutDriver: No parallelALS.props found on classpath, will use command-line arguments only
15/02/09 17:32:26 INFO common.AbstractJob: Command line arguments: {--alpha=[0.8], --endPhase=[2147483647], --implicitFeedback=[true], --input=[prova1.csv], --lambda=[0.1], --numFeatures=[2], --numIterations=[5], --numThreadsPerSolver=[1], --output=[output.csv], --startPhase=[0], --tempDir=[tmp]}
15/02/09 17:32:26 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
15/02/09 17:32:26 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.input.dir is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.inputdir
15/02/09 17:32:26 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.compress.map.output is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.map.output.compress
15/02/09 17:32:26 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.output.dir is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.outputdir
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobContext, but class was expected
    at org.apache.mahout.common.HadoopUtil.getCustomJobName(HadoopUtil.java:174)
    at org.apache.mahout.common.AbstractJob.prepareJob(AbstractJob.java:614)
    at org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.hadoop.als.ParallelALSFactorizationJob.run(ParallelALSFactorizationJob.java:166)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:84)
    at org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.hadoop.als.ParallelALSFactorizationJob.main(ParallelALSFactorizationJob.java:113)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver$ProgramDescription.invoke(ProgramDriver.java:71)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver.run(ProgramDriver.java:144)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver.driver(ProgramDriver.java:152)
    at org.apache.mahout.driver.MahoutDriver.main(MahoutDriver.java:195)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
Lore:~ lorenzoferri$
```

I also tried:

```
Lore:~ lorenzoferri$ mahout recommenditembased -i '/Users/lorenzoferri/Desktop/prova1.csv' -o '/Users/lorenzoferri/Desktop/output.csv' -n 100 -s SIMILARITY_COOCCURRENCE
No MAHOUT_CONF_DIR found
Running on hadoop, using /usr/local/bin/hadoop and HADOOP_CONF_DIR=
MAHOUT-JOB: /usr/local/Cellar/mahout/0.9/libexec/mahout-examples-0.9-job.jar
15/02/09 17:37:02 WARN driver.MahoutDriver: No recommenditembased.props found on classpath, will use command-line arguments only
15/02/09 17:37:02 INFO common.AbstractJob: Command line arguments: {--booleanData=[false], --endPhase=[2147483647], --input=[/Users/lorenzoferri/Desktop/prova1.csv], --maxPrefsInItemSimilarity=[500], --maxPrefsPerUser=[10], --maxSimilaritiesPerItem=[100], --minPrefsPerUser=[1], --numRecommendations=[100], --output=[/Users/lorenzoferri/Desktop/output.csv], --similarityClassname=[SIMILARITY_COOCCURRENCE], --startPhase=[0], --tempDir=[temp]}
15/02/09 17:37:02 INFO common.AbstractJob: Command line arguments: {--booleanData=[false], --endPhase=[2147483647], --input=[/Users/lorenzoferri/Desktop/prova1.csv], --minPrefsPerUser=[1], --output=[temp/preparePreferenceMatrix], --ratingShift=[0.0], --startPhase=[0], --tempDir=[temp]}
15/02/09 17:37:03 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
15/02/09 17:37:03 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.input.dir is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.inputdir
15/02/09 17:37:03 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.compress.map.output is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.map.output.compress
15/02/09 17:37:03 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.output.dir is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.outputdir
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobContext, but class was expected
    at org.apache.mahout.common.HadoopUtil.getCustomJobName(HadoopUtil.java:174)
    at org.apache.mahout.common.AbstractJob.prepareJob(AbstractJob.java:614)
    at org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.hadoop.preparation.PreparePreferenceMatrixJob.run(PreparePreferenceMatrixJob.java:73)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.hadoop.item.RecommenderJob.run(RecommenderJob.java:164)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.hadoop.item.RecommenderJob.main(RecommenderJob.java:322)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver$ProgramDescription.invoke(ProgramDriver.java:71)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver.run(ProgramDriver.java:144)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver.driver(ProgramDriver.java:152)
    at org.apache.mahout.driver.MahoutDriver.main(MahoutDriver.java:195)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
```

I installed mahout via brew, on mac os x 10.10, but i got the same problem on ubuntu. On the web i can only find tutorial on eclipse, but i would like to run it through the terminal.

Answer (score 2):

1. `No MAHOUT_CONF_DIR found`
   add to your .bash_profile or .zshrc:

   - `export MAHOUT=/path/to/mahout`
   - `export MAHOUT_CONF_DIR=$MAHOUT_HOME/conf`
2. In order to run Mahout locally 
   add to your .bash_profile or .zshrc:

   - `export MAHOUT_LOCAL="not-an-empty-string"`

   set to anything other than an empty string to force mahout to run locally
   even if `HADOOP_CONF_DIR`and `HADOOP_HOME` are set.

In order to get up and running quickly I will recommend for you to:

- Download mahout as a `tar.gz`: http://apache.mivzakim.net/mahout/0.9/mahout-distribution-0.9.tar.gz
- Follow steps 1 and 2 as mentioned, the `/path/to/mahout` is where you extracted `mahout-distribution-0.9`
- Run the mahout command from `mahout-distribution-0.9/bin/mahout`
- i.e: `./bin/mahout recommenditembased -i '/Users/lorenzoferri/Desktop/prova1.csv' -o '/Users/lorenzoferri/Desktop/output.csv' -n 100 -s SIMILARITY_COOCCURRENCE`
- In `mahout-distribution-0.9/examples` you can run and explore some shell scripts

https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/mahout/trunk/bin/mahout

Comment: What is `$MAHOUT_HOME` set to?

Comment: point to the extracted tar.gz for example

```$MAHOUT_HOME=~/machine_learning/mahout-distribution-0.9```